# Animating a re-ordered List with Livewire and Alpine JS

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, alpine.js

I have an alpine js and livewire component which is meant to display add and remove items from a list. Each item is displayed as a token.

This is the HTML code of a token:

```html
  <div
                    class="inline-block px-2 py-4"
                    x-data="{show : false}"
                    x-show="show"
                    x-init="setTimeout(() => {show=true}, 450)"
                    x-transition.duration.450>
                    <span class="px-4 py-3 space-x-1 rounded-full shadow bg-indigo-300 text-white font-light">
                        <span>{{ $item->name }}</span>
                        <span
                            class="font-bold text-xl cursor-pointer"
                            @click="show = false;
                                            setTimeout(() => {$wire.updateSelection({{ $item->id }})}, 400);">
                            &times;
                        </span>
                    </span>
                    <input type="text" name="clients[]" type="number" value="{{ $item->id }}" hidden />
                </div>
```

I need the token to disappear smoothly before it is removed from the DOM. In order to achieve this I have tried to apply the following code.

```
  @click="show = false; setTimeout(() => {$wire.updateSelection({{ $item->id }})}, 400);">
```

The problem is that once the token is hidden and then removed by the livewire method from the array the token that was next in the loop remains hidden due to the fact that the show property on it is now set to false. Why is that ?

Here is a demo: https://gfycat.com/brightbronzeherring

I tried to fix it by adding an additional setTimeout which does not work as smoothly. When using this solution a unwanted animation is added if you decide to remove the last displayed token:

```
  @click="show = false; setTimeout(() => {$wire.updateSelection({{ $item->id }})}, 400); setTimeout(() => {show=true}, 300);">
```

This is the php code of the livewire component:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire\Components;

use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection;
use Livewire\Component;

class ManyToManyDropdown extends Component
{
    public $selected;
    public $noUsers;
    public $link;


    // PTR add comments
    public function mount($link)
    {
        if (!empty($link)) { // when the form is used in the 'create' view we pass an empty string PTR

            $this->link = $link;
            $this->selected = $link->users; // load the users which have already been selected
            $this->noUsers = $this->selected->count() > 0 ? false : true; // determine if the 'no users message should be displayed'

        } else {

            $this->selected = new Collection();
            $this->noUsers = true;
        }

    }

    // PTR add comments
    public function updateSelection($id)
    {
        // validate the data
        $valid = User::all()->pluck('id')->contains($id);

        if (!$valid) { // if data validation fails - abort
            return abort(404);
        }


        // persis the data
        $found = $this->selected->pluck('id')->contains($id);

        $user = User::find($id);

        if ($found) { // in case the item is already in the collection we remove it

            $this->selected = $this->selected->filter(function ($item) use ($id) {
                return $item->id != $id;
            });

        } else { // in case the item is not in the collection then it is added

            $this->selected->push($user);
        }

        $this->noUsers = $this->selected->count() == 0 ? true :false ;  // check if a 'no items message should be shown'
    }

    // PTR add comments
    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.components.many-to-many-dropdown', [
            'users' => User::clients()->get()
        ]);
    }
}
```

This is the HTML:

```html
<div class="space-y-4">
    <!-- Clients -->
    <div>

        <x-label class="font-bold" for="Client" :value="__('Client:')" />

        <div>

            @foreach ($selected as $item)

                <div
                    class="inline-block px-2 py-4"
                    x-data="{show : false}"
                    x-show="show"
                    x-init="setTimeout(() => {show=true}, 450)"
                    x-transition.duration.450>
                    <span class="px-4 py-3 space-x-1 rounded-full shadow bg-indigo-300 text-white font-light">
                        <span>{{ $item->name }}</span>
                        <span
                            class="font-bold text-xl cursor-pointer"
                            @click="show = false;
                            setTimeout(() => {$wire.updateSelection({{ $item->id }})}, 400);
                            setTimeout(() => {show=true}, 300);">
                            &times;
                        </span>
                    </span>
                    <input type="text" name="clients[]" type="number" value="{{ $item->id }}" hidden />
                </div>

            @endforeach

        </div>



        {{-- message in case there are not users selcted for this link --}}
        <div x-data="{show: @entangle('noUsers')}" x-show="show" x-transition.duration.450ms
            class="mt-1 px-2 py-2 cursor-not-allowed text-sm rounded-md shadow-sm border border-gray-400 itlaic font-hairline">
            There are no customers selected...
        </div>

    </div>

    <!-- Dropdown -->
    <div>
        <x-label class="font-bold" :value="__('Assign to:')" />


        <div x-data="{show:false}" class="mt-1 relative">

            <button
                @click="show = !show;" type="button"
                class="relative w-full bg-white border border-gray-300 rounded-md shadow-sm pl-3 pr-10 py-2 text-left cursor-default focus:outline-none focus:ring-1 focus:ring-indigo-300 focus:border-indigo-500 sm:text-sm"
                aria-haspopup="listbox"
                aria-expanded="true"
                aria-labelledby="listbox-label">
                <span x-ref="button" class="block truncate">
                    Select users...
                </span>
                <span class="absolute inset-y-0 right-0 flex items-center pr-2 pointer-events-none">
                    <!-- Heroicon name: solid/selector -->
                    <svg class="h-5 w-5 text-gray-400" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20"
                        fill="currentColor" aria-hidden="true">
                        <path fill-rule="evenodd"
                            d="M10 3a1 1 0 01.707.293l3 3a1 1 0 01-1.414 1.414L10 5.414 7.707 7.707a1 1 0 01-1.414-1.414l3-3A1 1 0 0110 3zm-3.707 9.293a1 1 0 011.414 0L10 14.586l2.293-2.293a1 1 0 011.414 1.414l-3 3a1 1 0 01-1.414 0l-3-3a1 1 0 010-1.414z"
                            clip-rule="evenodd" />
                    </svg>
                </span>
            </button>


            <ul x-show="show" x-transition:enter="transition ease-out duration-300" x-transition:enter-start="opacity-0"
                x-transition:enter-end="opacity-100" @click.away='show = false'
                class="absolute z-10 mt-1 w-full bg-white shadow-lg max-h-60 rounded-md py-1 text-base ring-1 ring-black ring-opacity-5 overflow-auto focus:outline-none sm:text-sm"
                tabindex="-1" role="listbox" aria-labelledby="listbox-label" aria-activedescendant="listbox-option-3">

                @foreach ($users as $user)

                    {{-- in case the array contains tha user I remove it, otherwise I add it --}}
                    <li x-data="{showCheck : false}" @click="showCheck = !showCheck"
                        wire:click="updateSelection('{{ $user->id }}')"
                        class="text-gray-900 cursor-default select-none relative py-2 pl-8 pr-4 hover:bg-blue-300 hover:text-white"
                        role="option">
                        <span class="font-normal block truncate">
                            {{ $user->name }}
                        </span>


                        <span x-show="showCheck" x-transition.duration.400ms
                            class="text-indigo-600 absolute inset-y-0 left-0 flex items-center pl-1.5">
                            <!-- Heroicon name: solid/check -->
                            <svg class="h-5 w-5" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20"
                                fill="currentColor" aria-hidden="true">
                                <path fill-rule="evenodd"
                                    d="M16.707 5.293a1 1 0 010 1.414l-8 8a1 1 0 01-1.414 0l-4-4a1 1 0 011.414-1.414L8 12.586l7.293-7.293a1 1 0 011.414 0z"
                                    clip-rule="evenodd" />
                            </svg>
                        </span>
                    </li>

                @endforeach

            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a missing `wire:key={{$item->id}}`

when implementing the `@foreach` in the view

More information can be found here:

- https://laravel-livewire.com/screencasts/s8-animate-move
- https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/nesting-components#keyed-components